# Generate JS from XSD using maven?

Tags: java, javascript, maven, code-generation, maven-plugin

I can use this maven plugin `maven-jaxb-plugin` to generate Java Classes from XSD file.
Now I want to generate JavaScript classes from XSD, and using maven too. Do you have any idea?

In case of there is no maven plugin for generating js from xsd, is there any good way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't have any kind of similar experience using Maven and Java, but one thing just came to my mind. As I see after googling for a while, there's no such tool you're asking for. But maybe 2-step processing would work here? You can use [JAXB](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) to generate Java classes from XSD and then use tool like [STJS](http://st-js.org/) to generate JavaScript from that Java. As I said, I can't say anything from my personal experience, but I would try this and see how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check with STJS soon. Actually, I am using JAXB currently to generate Java Classes. So let me try with STJS now.

Comment: Another thing... Good to see in the web that there is Maven Artifact for this. :)) But will try it soon...